# How can I propagate a View Helper variable to a distant View child in ZF2, without using pass-through code?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I do not have full ZF2 stack but I rigged my mostly-non-ZF2 code to accept `$this->partial()` and `ViewModel()` methods.

I often find a situation where I have a tree of View Helper Partials, to where some distant-from-root child needs a variable `someVar`.

I manage that variable passing it through each `partial` from root to the child, even when the in-route partials have no need for it.

Is there a way to not have to manage the var?

**Example**

```
//controller.php
echo $this->partial('root.phtml', array('someVar' => $someVar));
```

```php
//root.phtml
<? 
    //this variable-pass-through-only step is one I would like to eliminate.
    //aka. here someVar is not itself used in root.phtml
    //it is only passed onto the child view partial
    //I want to eliminate this pass-through-only code.

    echo $this->partial('child.phtml', array('someVar' => $this->someVar)):
?>
```

```php
//child.phtml - leaf child
<?
    //variable is actually used for display purpose
    echo $this->someVar;
?>
```

I am open to answers that use non-`partial` construct, i.e. `ViewModel`, etc.

Note:  when I remove the pass-through code, hoping there is some kind of global scope for vars, it is not the case - the variable does not pass onto the child leaf view partial.  I am hoping there is some kind of a better approach in ZF2 for what I want to do.

**Goal / Spirit of the Question**

To be clear I am seeking a way to make some vars to be a "global" var that  extends itself from root of `partial`/`view` to the leaf `.phtml` without pass-through code,  or perhaps a different approach altogether to where I do not need to do this, and yet not clutter my code with pass-through vars

Comment: What kind of templates / variable are we talking about here? Some nested tree-rendering? How complex are the individual partials? The reason why I'm asking is, that as usual in ZF2, there are about 20 ways to achieve a goal, which one the right one is often greatly depends on the situation :)

Comment: Perhaps use the placeholder helper?

Comment: @Fge in my case I have an `isAnOrder` boolean variable that is used in an if-then-else construct in my leaf child partial.  But sometimes I also have arrays of variables, such as more boolean variables that are just passed through.

Comment: I assume you are re-using this view at some locations, so taking the approach @AlexP suggested probably is the best way of doing so. If you don't re-use it, try to flatten your view template hierachy. A bit of redundency in the views is fine too. When creating re-usable ViewModels, don't shy away of defering this task to a dedicated service that different controllers can use to build the child-view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `ViewModel` instances to replicate the functionality of the partial view helper. By having the objects independently created there is no need to pass all variables to each of them.

A simple example.

```
$main = new ViewModel(['var1' => 'xyz', 'var2' => 'xyz']);
$main->setTemplate('main.phtml');

$foo = new ViewModel(['baz' => 'bob']);
$foo->setTemplate('foo.phtml');

$bar = new ViewModel(['test' => 123]);
$bar->setTemplate('bar.phtml');

// foo.phtml should echo $this->barResultHtml
$foo->addChild($bar, 'barResultHtml');

// main.phtml should echo $this->fooResultHtml
$main->addChild($foo, 'fooResultHtml');

// You will need to set this up to render the view model.
$view = new Zend\View\View();
$view->setRenderer(...);

echo $view->render($main);
```

Comment: thanks.  that appears to 'consolidate" all variable assignment into a single script, aka `example.php` and sort them out into individual respective `ViewModel` children.  And then `render()` does the rest.  I concur is pretty cool.  Let me try this out I will report back..

Comment: cool it seems to be working... still cleaning up the massive Gordian Knot of a code